# Bootstrap 4 is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to integrate `bootstrap4` to my website but the `navbar` is not working. All the attributes is crossout in the css. Can someone help me about this?

result
[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: These properties are crossed out since they are superceded by some other properties with more priority.

Comment: Did you check which styling DOES affect your element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a wrong combination of bootstrap version and classes.

You are using the **bootstrap4 alpha** version and the `.navbar-expand` class comes in **bootstra4 beta**.

***Stack Snippet*** <sup>Using Bootstrap4.beta</sup>

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-light">
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But if you want to continue with bootstrap alpha version you have to use `.navbar-toggleable` instead of `.navbar-expand` and also some extra css as
`.navbar-toggleable` works till `min-width: 576px`

***Stack Snippet*** <sup>Using Bootstrap4.alpha</sup>

```css
.navbar-toggleable .navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-toggleable .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable navbar-light bg-faded">
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried that but still some of it are crossed out :3

Comment: @nethkennnnn you have used bootstrap4.alpha or bootstrap4.beta??

Answer (score -1):

add !important to the css.
eg

```
.navbar-toggleable .navbar-nav {
flex-direction: row !important;
flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
align-items: center !important;
}
```

hope is it helped.

Comment: definitely but  well you can try this downgrade from v4.4 to v4.2 that is more stable and it works with your source code. hope it helps